# OIOSAML Maven integration

Tags: java, maven, gwt, saml-2.0, opensaml

I came across the project(OIOSAML, based on OpenSAML) and thought it was great and very easy to try out with the demo and implement in a simple war-project. Within a few minutes i was set up to access my ADFS.

However when going over to my current project(that uses GWT & builds with Maven) i found it difficult to add all the dependencies. I found no repository or any good way to add all the libraries. Maven keeps trying to look for xescer:xml-apis:1.4.01 (which isn't included in the OIOSAML lib/ folder) so my question is: Does anyone have expereince setting up OIOSAML with Maven? Could you please lend a hand?

TL;DR

Can't get OIOSAML.java working wtih Maven, need help.

If you want payment for your time maybe we can arrange that. Contact me here on the forums or via email and we cant take it from there or by phone.

Kind regards,

Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After manually adding every dependency to our Sonatype Nexus and creating a new maven war project, it finally worked. It doesn't work with our main project though as dependencies are clashing.

I guess sometimes it's good to re-invent the wheel to be able to reduce the amount of dependencies clashing. Especially for something like this which could be used in and kind of project.